# if $f$ is differentaible at $z_{0}$, does u and v have continuous partial derivatives?

Tags: complex-analysis

I know the following theorem.

Theorem

For the complex function $f=u+iv$,

1. u and v are have continuous partial derivatives at $z_{0}$
2. u and v satisfies the Cauchy Riemann equation at $z_{0}$

,then $f$ is differentaible at $z_{0}$.

Question: Does the converse hold?

Especially, if $f$ is differentaible at $z_{0}$, does u and v have continuous partial derivatives?

If not, let me know the counter example, please.

Comment: A complex-valued function of a complex variable is differentiable at $z_0$ iff 1) its $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ counterpart is $C^1$, and 2) the C-R equations are satisfied. An equivalent condition for the real part to be $C^1$ is the partials existing and being continuous at $z_0$.

Answer (score 0):

The converse is actually false. Take $f(z)=z|z|$. The function $f(z)$ is differentiable at $z=0$ with $f'(z)=0$. The real part of $f(z)$ is $u(x,y)=x(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}$, with it's partial derivative $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}+\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$. You can easily check that the limit of $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ as $(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)$ does not exist. So the partial derivative may not be continuous.